# How to download images and bounding boxes from imageNet?

Tags: dataset, object-detection

I am doing object detection for a specific class, say, `chairs` .

I want to download images of chairs from imageNet. I also want to download the annotation xml files (bounding boxes) from imageNet.

Both these things are provided on imageNet and I have successfully been able to download them using a tool called `ImageNet_Utils`

https://github.com/tzutalin/ImageNet_Utils

But the downloaded images and bounding boxes don't have matching names. So it is impossible to tell which xml file is for which image.

How do I download images and bounding boxes from imageNet such that corresponding image and annotation xml files have matching names?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @user3731622 I didn't use the tool mentioned above. I downloaded the images and annotation files directly from ImageNet. You have to first apply stating that you need the dataset for academic purposes only. A couple days later, you are given access. When you download from ImageNet, the images and annotation files have the same names.

Answer (score 1):

> But the downloaded images and bounding boxes don't have matching  ames. So it is impossible to tell which xml file is for which image.

I don't think that happens, image and annotation may have same name. But Bbox and image is odd.

Still if you meant image and annotation that would be odd.

Comment: The annotation file and the image don't have matching names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapping described [here](http://image-net.org/download-API):

> **Access (image names, image URLs) mapping by synset ID**
>
> If you download the original images of a synset from a tar file, you
> may want to know the original image URLs given the image names. You
> can obtain the mapping between image names and image URLs through
> [http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls.getmapping?wnid=[wnid]](http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls.getmapping?wnid=%5Bwnid%5D)